# How to extract one query at a time from an SQL file?

Tags: bash, sql

I am trying to extract  one query at a time from an SQL file.

This is what I have tried

```
index1=1
index2=1
while read -n1 char; do
if [[ $char == ";" ]]
  then
     SUBSTRING=$(awk 'substr($index1,$index2)' sql1Temp.sql)
     echo $SUBSTRING 
    index1=$index2
fi 
((index2+=1))

done <sql1Temp.sql
```

My SQL file look like this:

sqlFile.sql

select *from test1;

select *from test2;

select *from test3;

I am getting this as a result:

```
wedtorque@wedtorque-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ ./masterFile.sh
select *from test1; select *from test2; select *from test3;
select *from test1; select *from test2; select *from test3;
select *from test1; select *from test2; select *from test3;
wedtorque@wedtorque-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$
```

Whereas I was expecting something like this:

```
wedtorque@wedtorque-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ ./masterFile.sh
select *from test1;
select *from test1;
select *from test1;
wedtorque@wedtorque-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$
```

Also when I echo the `$char` inside while loop, it prints the file names every time `$char` gets the `*` from queries, `select *from test1`; etc

Something like this

```
wedtorque@wedtorque-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ ./masterFile.sh
s
e
l
e
c
t

masterFile.sh sql1result.sql sql1.sql sql1Temp.sql sql2.sql Untitled Document
f
r
o
m

t
e
s
t
1
select *from test1; select *from test2; select *from test3;
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are doing, but I'll take a guess.

The .sql file, in my test case I'll call it `test.sql`:

```
select * from test1;
select * from test2;
select * from test3;
```

And the script to read and echo that sql data:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Get the raw sql data
RAW=`cat test.sql`

# We want to split the raw sql on a line return.
IFS="
"

# Echo out each line? Not sure if this is what you want.
for sql in $RAW
do
    echo "SQL line: [${sql}]"
done

exit
```

This will give you the following result:

```
SQL line: [select * from test1;]
SQL line: [select * from test2;]
SQL line: [select * from test3;]
```

I think the bit you are missing is the `IFS` part. From `man sh`:

```
IFS  Input Field Separators. This is normally set to ⟨space⟩, 
     ⟨tab⟩, and ⟨newline⟩.
```